# Need Cron expression to trigger job for every 90 minutes in AWS Glue

Tags: cron

In AWS glue service there is an option to trigger job by custom CRON expression. Before i used this (0/2 * * ? *) cron expression to trigger job for every 2 hours.
Now I need to change the cron expression to trigger every 90 minutes, i.e for every 1 and a half hour. I tried with many cron expressions but that did not triggered for every 90 minutes. Even if i give for 90 minutes, it trigged for every 1 hour.

Can anyone help me out by providing the correct cron expression to trigger job for every 90 minutes ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following pattern which was based on [Bill Weiss' answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/123633).  It was modified to comply with the unique syntax AWS uses ([reference here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-data-warehouse-schedule.html?icmpid=docs_glue_console)):

```
0 0-21/3 * * ? *
30 1-22/3 * * ? *
```

You'll have to define two separate Glue Triggers to accomplish this, each with the same job settings.

If curious, the syntax reads:

> 1. Run every 0th minute for every third hour for 0-21 hours
> 2. Run every 30th minute for every third hour for 1-22 hours